# how can i use loop in array of array (php)?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop, telegram-bot

i wanna use Repeat loop (for , while and etc ... )in array of array of in php :

```
      for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {

         $poets = array(
        'keyboard' => array(

            array($saves[$x]) // this is just one array i don't want this !

        ),
    );
$url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?
chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".$text."&reply_markup=".$jsonPoets;
file_get_contents($url);


}
```

this is not working , i wanna do like this :

```
 for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {

         $poets = array(
        'keyboard' => array(

       //i wanna do like this ...

            array($saves[$x])
          //array($saves[$x])
          //array($saves[$x])
                 .
                 .
                 .

        )
    );
$url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?
chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".$text."&reply_markup=".$jsonPoets;
file_get_contents($url);


}
```

it means i wanna make multi array in array with loop repeat .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$poets= array('keyboard' => array());
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
   $poets['keyboard'][] = array($saves[$x]);
}
```

Like this?